# How to make FirebaseApp don't initialize again when back to MainActivity?

Tags: android, firebase

I am a beginner in learning Android studio and bad at English.

I have two Firebase projects in an android app and writing these code below.

```
     FirebaseOptions options1 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setProjectId("fd-login-20e78")
                .setApplicationId("...")
                .setApiKey("...")
                .build();

        FirebaseOptions options2 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setProjectId("fd-login1-dc1f7")
                .setApplicationId("...")
                .setApiKey("...")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options1, "first");
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options2, "secondary");

        FirebaseApp first = FirebaseApp.getInstance("first");
        FirebaseApp secondary = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
```

It work pretty well without any crash. But when I trying to go back to MainActivity from other Activities, it always crash and have this error :

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name first already exists!**

I know the problem occurs because FirebaseApp is initialized again. How could I stop it when I back to MainAcitvity?

I had tried this way to solve the problem but it didn't work. The code below make App crash immediately. Errors shows that  it doesn't initialize anything.

```
if (FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options1, "first");
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options2, "secondary");
}
```

Edit

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private TextView tv_register, tv_forget;
    private EditText ed_email1, ed_password1;
    private Button btn_login;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth, mAuth2, mAuth3, login;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    FirebaseApp first,secondary;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv_register = findViewById(R.id.tv_register2);
        tv_register.setOnClickListener(this);

        tv_forget = findViewById(R.id.tv_forget2);
        tv_forget.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login2);
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);

        ed_email1 = findViewById(R.id.ed_email2);
        ed_password1 = findViewById(R.id.ed_password2);

        rb1 = findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb2 = findViewById(R.id.rb2);
        rb3 = findViewById(R.id.rb3);
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        FirebaseOptions options1 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setProjectId("fd-login-20e78")
                    .setApplicationId("...")
                    .setApiKey("...")
                    .build();

        FirebaseOptions options2 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setProjectId("fd-login1-dc1f7")
                    .setApplicationId("...")
                    .setApiKey("...")
                    .build();
            
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options1, "first");
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options2, "secondary");


        first = FirebaseApp.getInstance("first");
        secondary = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(first);
        mAuth2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(secondary);
    }
```

Comment: How are you going back to MainActivity? using intent?

Comment: Yse. I using Intent to go back to MainActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If going back to `MainActivity()` using `onBackPressed()` is an option, meaning if the second activity is loaded from `MainActivity()` and you just want to go back, write the Firebase initialization logic in the `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity()` and use `onBackPressed()` in the second activity to go back to the `MainActivity()` like so:

Instead of the following:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity :: class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

just write this:

```
onBackPressed()
```

If you are in a fragment use this:

```
activity?.onBackPressed()
```

This way, since you are using the `onBackPressed()` function and not an intent, a new instance of `MainActivity()` will not be created and the same instance which is available in the back stack will be loaded. As a result, onCreate() will not be called again. Instead, `onResume()` is called so the initialization logic will not run.

Comment: Just edited my answer. check it out.

Comment: Thank you. I have try your solution and it execute without any crash!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Application` class whose `onCreate()` method is only called at the start of the app and never after. For this, create a separate java class called `MyApplication` (or whatever name you like), extend it with `Application` class and in it's `onCreate()` method, execute your code like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseOptions options1 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setProjectId("fd-login-20e78")
                .setApplicationId("...")
                .setApiKey("...")
                .build();

        FirebaseOptions options2 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setProjectId("fd-login1-dc1f7")
                .setApplicationId("...")
                .setApiKey("...")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options1, "first");
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this , options2, "secondary");

        FirebaseApp first = FirebaseApp.getInstance("first");
        FirebaseApp secondary = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
    }
}
```

One more thing you have to do is to declare `MyApplication` name in `AndroidManifest` within `application` tag like this:

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

That's it. Let me know if something breaks.

Comment: How about the OnCreat method that I already exist? I don't know how to write it in correct place.  I will edit my post to show the code.